# How to destroy dynamic elements from panel in unity c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to delete the items from the panel (empty it) and then repopulate the panel with new items (buttons)

I've already tried to delete each element with the foreach you see below with no luck

```
public GameObject Button;
public Transform buttonContainer;
public void create_buttons(Orbital o)
{
    GameObject go = Instantiate(Button);
    var panel = GameObject.Find("station_panel");
    //Destroy(GameObject.Find("station_panel"));

    foreach (UnityEngine.UI.Button b in panel.GetComponents<UnityEngine.UI.Button>())
    {
        //Destroy(b.gameObject);
        b.enabled = false;
    }

    go.transform.position = panel.transform.position;
    go.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetParent(panel.transform);
    //go.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(RectTransform.Edge.Left, 0, 10);

    go.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => onClick());
    go.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = o.name;
}
void onClick()
{
    Debug.Log("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");


    canvas.enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you expect your code to do and what happens instead? It is not quite clear from your question yet.

Comment: There is a panel. I add buttons dynamically to it. That happens. But on every iteration new buttons get added to the panel, essentially duplicating the old ones. I want to first empty/destroy whatever is in the panel and then add buttons to it again. Something like initializing the panel to an empty one (btw can't destroy the panel), and then repopulating it

Comment: Btw instead of the `foreach` loop you could simply make the prefab field of type `public Button Button;`. then you would get the component directly from `Button go = Instantiate (Button, panel.transform); go.enabled = false;` and you could also skip the next two lines `go.transform.position = panel.transform.position;
    go.GetComponent<RectTransform>().SetParent(panel.transform);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The panel's transform hierarchy contains a reference to them.

```
Transform panelTransform = GameObject.Find("station_panel").transform;
foreach(Transform child in panelTransform) {
    Destroy(child.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `Destroy(child.gameObject);`

Comment: I would also recommend to not use `Find` but rather store the reference either the first time it was called e.g. like `private GameObject panel; private Transform GetPanelTransform { get { if(!panel) { panel = Find("station_panel"); } return panel.transform; } }`. Or to not use `Find` at all and rather link the reference in the Inspector using `[SerializeField] private Transform panelTransform;`

Comment: @derHugo Also that, but I wasn't going to get into it here. All I wanted to show was the transform hierarchy was traverseable.

Answer (score 1):

Make a List and add any button you create for your panel.

Once you want to clear it, clear this list, but GetCompoenents will not return all the buttons in your Panel gameobject as you cant add 2 button component to a single gameobject.

Also add -using UnityEngine.UI- to the top of your script to be easily read for to be like

```
 foreach (Button b in list)
{
    Destroy(b.gameObject);        
}
```

Comment: If doing that (which is a valid alternative to the other answer) make sure you also do `list.Clear();` afterwards to also remove all the entries for the references to the destroyed objects which now are `null` bit still there.

Answer (score 1):

DestroyImmediate(i-am-gameobject);